# Protobuf "oneof" functionality not working

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a this sample protobuf message:

```
message testMessage{    
    oneof oneOfTest{
        string test2 = 2;
        int32 test3 = 3;   
    } 
}
```

But it is failing to compile, saying:

```
[ERROR] protoc failed error: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
test.proto: Missing field number.
```

Based on the line numbers, it is looking for that required/optional/repeated keyworkd before "oneof" and it is complaining of the missing field number after "oneOfTest". Is this not the correct way to use oneof? I am using the java compiler for Protobuf.

Comment: Have you tried adding one of those keywords where it says you should have one? What happens then?

Comment: Are you using the most recent protocol buffer compiler?  `oneof` was added in 2.6, which appears to have been released last Monday.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That was it, thanks! I didn't realize the `oneof` feature was new. If you want write your comment as the question, I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you're using the most recent version of the protocol buffer compiler: `oneof` syntax was added in only the very most recent version, released last Monday.

Comment: And if you're using pre-2.6 protoc, it gives a misleading error message prompting you to add "required" or "optional" in front of your "oneof." If you do that, then switch to 2.6 protoc, it won't understand what you're doing until you remove the "required" or "optional."